# Pandas: How to fill nan value for column with part of value in other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

I Want the value in city column to be filled with first word of venue column

[image]

I tried using
`df.city.fillna(value=df.venue.str.split()[0])`
but it taking first row values to fill
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your `DataFrame` :

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from io import StringIO

>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
id,city,venue
2343242,NaN,Sharjah Cricket Stadium
4354534,NaN,Dubai Internationnl Cricket Stadium
4564564,NaN,Dubai Internationnl Cricket Stadium
3454355,NaN,Sharjah Cricket Stadium
5676575,NaN,Sharjah Cricket Stadium"""))
>>> df
    id          city    venue
0   2343242     NaN     Sharjah Cricket Stadium
1   4354534     NaN     Dubai Internationnl Cricket Stadium
2   4564564     NaN     Dubai Internationnl Cricket Stadium
3   3454355     NaN     Sharjah Cricket Stadium
4   5676575     NaN     Sharjah Cricket Stadium
```

After the `split()` you used, we can use `map` to assign the first list element to the `NaN` values in the `City` column as expected :

```py
>>> df['city'] = df['city'].fillna(value=df['venue'].str.split().map(lambda x: x[0]))
>>> df
    id          city        venue
0   2343242     Sharjah     Sharjah Cricket Stadium
1   4354534     Dubai       Dubai Internationnl Cricket Stadium
2   4564564     Dubai       Dubai Internationnl Cricket Stadium
3   3454355     Sharjah     Sharjah Cricket Stadium
4   5676575     Sharjah     Sharjah Cricket Stadium
```

EDIT:

Even shorter, thanks to @HenryEcker :

```py
>>> df['city'] = df['city'].fillna(value=df['venue'].str.split().str[0])
>>> df
    id          city        venue
0   2343242     Sharjah     Sharjah Cricket Stadium
1   4354534     Dubai       Dubai Internationnl Cricket Stadium
2   4564564     Dubai       Dubai Internationnl Cricket Stadium
3   3454355     Sharjah     Sharjah Cricket Stadium
4   5676575     Sharjah     Sharjah Cricket Stadium
```

Comment: Maybe `df['city'] = df['city'].fillna(value=df['venue'].str.split().str[0])` instead of `map` and `lambda`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with parameter `expand=True` to expand split words to different columns and get the first column `0` to feed into the [`.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) function for column `city`, as follows:

```
df['city'] = df['city'].fillna(df['venue'].str.split(' ', expand=True)[0])
```

or split to a list with default `expand=False` and use `str[0]` to get the first item in list:

```
df['city'] = df['city'].fillna(df['venue'].str.split().str[0])
```

In this way, we don't need to use non-vectorized lambda or apply functions.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
df['city'] = df.venue.apply(lambda x: x.split()[0])
```

Comment: Actually it replace for all the other value , i just want it to replace for nan values. Thank you for your ans